# Migration to new version of JSF with feature-rich but more compatible library

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

Currently I am using JSF 1.1 (Myfaces library). I am considering moving to JSF 2.0 and towards a more feature-rich implementation library but at the same time considering that migration issues must be as less as possible. People with the experience of JSF, please suggest.

Comment: I am particularly keen to know about migration to RichFaces given the above considerations.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your comment regarding RichFaces:

RichFaces 4, that is supposed to support JSF2, supports only some of the components. See [Milestone 1](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.0.X/4.0.0.Milestone1/Component_Reference/en-US/html/index.html) documentation.

As well, if you used their CDK to create components, it will not work in JSF2.

However, I will definitely recommend to you to use [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/). You can see in the [demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf) variety of components that are supported in JSF2.

BUT:

If you have many RichFaces components in your code, you may consider to upgrade a new model, and not the same one. It may require too much work and it's not clear when RichFaces are going to release the full component library for JSF2.

Comment: so there's no complete reference implementation of JSF 2.0! interesting. BTW, PrimeFaces seems really cool(from feature list and demo gallery) but as I said, I'm currently using JSF 1.1 MyFaces tomahawk component library and I don't clearly see how severe would be the migration incompatibilities. Any comment from experience in that regard would be more helpful.

Comment: @nabe: There are certainly complete reference implementations of JSF 2.0: it are Mojarra 2.x and MyFaces 2.x. I think you confused it with "component library". IceFaces, RichFaces, PrimeFaces, OpenFaces, etc are component libraries. The first two aren't fully JSF 2.0 ready yet, the latter ones are.